# Does PhpStorm understand bootstrap-vue?

Tags: phpstorm, bootstrap-vue

In PhpStorm 2019.2.3 working with vue 2.6 / bootstrap-vue 2.3
I see some syntax errors:

[image]

Looks like PhpStorm does not understand bootstrap-vue. Are there some intentions to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does support bootstrap-vue, but doesn't treat custom components as `<input>` elements `<label>` can be associated with. Please follow [WEB-43981](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-43981) for updates.

For now, I can suggest disabling **Unresolved ID** inspection in **Settings | Editor | Inspections | XML**